# Continuity of second derivate respect a first derivate in a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

> Let $E$ a open subset of $\mathbb R^n$  containing $X_o$ and suppose $f \in C^1(E)$. Let $x(t)$ the solution to the PVI:
>   $$
> x'=f(x), x(0)=x_0
> $$
>   in a interval $I$. Prove that the second derivative $x''(t)$ is continuous in I.

I'm trying to prove this, but all I do is digress with the definition of continuity, can anyone help me, maybe a hint? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use that in
$$
x'(t)=f(t,x(t))
$$
the right side, and thus also the left, is once continuously differentiable in $t$ as composition of $C^1$ functions.